# Developer Story: total duration for jobs that have just years seem incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

Steps to reproduce:

- add a new Position
- fill required fields
- for `Dates` pick `(no month) 2015` to `(no month) 2016`

Expected: `Position 2015 → 2016 (1 years)`

Actual: `Position 2015 → 2016 (2 years)`

I guess it's arguable if it's a bug or not, because the months are not selected at all, but it *feels* wrong to have 2015-2016 show up as two years instead of one.

Comment: Well, 2015-01-01 to 2016-12-31 is closer to two years than to one year, yes?  Really though, the interface should just let you type in the duration yourself instead of trying to calculate it for you.

Comment: But surely if the months aren't specified it should assume the same month in both years, most reasonably January?

Comment: Personally, I think it you can't put actual dates in, it should avoid saying _any_ number of years, because it's going to be absolutely wrong half of the time.

Comment: For a current position, it actually lists the number of months too. So a position `2015-now` shows up as `2 years and 1 month` right now. Displaying the number of months suggests an accuracy that isn't there.

Answer (score -2):

We decided to round up in the duration calculation so as not to shortchange users.

We do realize that rounding up may not be ideal for all story items, so we are currently looking into improvements that will give you more control and flexibility around dates and duration.